# Need a jQuery tabs restrictions active one tab at one status time using mvc5 controller

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 4 status in database table in status column like 1 , 2, 3 and 4.
I need jQuery tab or javascript tab and tab names like Tab A , Tab B , Tab C and Tab D.

Suppose from controller status is coming 1 then Tab A should active and other user should not access other 3 tabs restrictions to not open.

Like status 2 then Tab B should open and other restricted to open and moved to others tabs.
Same like status 3 then Tab C and status 4 then tab D and other all restrictions to open and access.

here is my static html tab

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        $("#action").on("click", function () { });
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-A">tabs-A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-B">tabs-B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-C">tabs-C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-D">tabs-D</a></li>

    </ul>

<div id="tabs-A">
    Tab A

</div>

<div id="tabs-B">
        Tab B

</div>
<div id="tabs-C">
        Tab C

</div>
<div id="tabs-D">
        Tab D

</div>


</div>
```

Below is my MVC controller method is passing single status

```
public ActionResult getStatus()
    {
        MyDbContext _db = new MyDbContext();
       //here i am passing status 1,2,3 and 4

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on your script tag:
[Check sample here via dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pTuEir)

```
$(function(){
    var statusList = [1,2,3,4]; --Make sure your tablist and this status array is aligned
    var selectedStatusIndex = statusList.indexOf(@Model);
    var activeIndex = 0;

    if (selectedStatusIndex > -1){
        activeIndex = selectedStatusIndex;
    }

    $("#tabs").tabs({
        active: activeIndex,
        disabled:true --disable all tabs
    });

    if (selectedStatusIndex === -1){
        $("#tabs").tabs("enable"); --enable all tab
    }
});
```

Comment: Can explain fully code from controller. @tontonsevilla

Comment: your code is not working can you share jsfiddle. @tontonsevilla

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan, i update my post. You can check the link.